# Is there a possibility to update node.js in Github Codespaces?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, codespaces

I am starting to develop VS Code and following the guide has let me to the point I'm not able to continue with Codespaces without upgrading node.js version.

I was at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build so I'm trying to run `yarn` and I get this.

```bash
@p4nu ➜ /workspaces/vscode $ yarn
yarn install v1.22.19
$ node build/npm/preinstall.js
*** Please use node.js versions >=16.14.x and <17.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
@p4nu ➜ /workspaces/vscode $ node -v
v14.19.3
```

I have searched here for any available answers using tags `[visual-studio-code]`, `[codespaces]` and `[node.js]` but I found none.

Answer (score 3):

After looking for answers I stumbled upon [this documentation step](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/setting-up-your-nodejs-project-for-codespaces#step-2-add-a-dev-container-configuration-to-your-repository-from-a-template).

I tried adding a new configuration file but I noticed (not for my surprise) this was [already made in this project](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/blob/30f4812b6552fbc1ca79ebd0a85ac6bd5ed2f80e/repository-containers/images/github.com/microsoft/vscode/.devcontainer/base.Dockerfile#L3). It fetches the dev-container image which is referencing the node.js version 14.

It would be possible to update node.js version inside the `devcontainer.json` file, but for this repo I think it's out of the question. I'll just set up things locally in my case.

Edit: I have updated the nodejs in another repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/pull/1483) which allows the newer node.js to be used in Codespaces.